# how do you merge multiple columns based on multiple conditions?

Tags: r

The values under hour1 to hour 6 are number of people waiting.

```
day hour1 hour2 hour3 hour4 hour5 hour6
1      4      1    2     1    2    6 
2      1      1    1     4    4    1 
3      3      5    4     1    3    6 
4      1      1    2     2    2    3 
5      2      4    3     3    3    5
6      1      2    1     2    4    2
```

```
day  hour   waiting 
1    hour1   4
2    hour2   1
3    hour3   4
4    hour4   2
5    hour5   3
6    hour6   2
7    hour1
8    hour2
9    hour3
10    hour4
11    hour5
12    hour6
```

The dataframe is much longer (my dataframe has 100 days, but lets pretend that this is just the start and the 3 columns need to follow this pattern. Please don't to copy the dataframe I created directly, and pretend that this is a much larger dataframe.

Comment: look at `tidyr::pivot_longer()`

Comment: `pivot_longer` covered at the duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57939670/496803 - as well as a host of other solutions.